# Convert Sums of absolute values in Linear program

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

Ihave the following problem and it needs to be converted into LP form.

\begin{align}
 \max\> & z = c^T x\\
      & Ax \leq B \\
      & \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|=1
\end{align}

I know that $c^Tx$ and $Ax \leq B$ are matrix dot products.
My question is, How can I convert $\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|=1$ into LP form.

I have read online that if you only have a finite amount of $x$'s, you can simply do one equation for the positive and another one for the negative. For instance, if we have $|x_1| = 1$, the equation will be transformed to $x_1 = 1$ and $-x_1 = 1$. How can we do it for the summation?

I think we need to take the combinations of all the possible $x$'s as maybe $x_1$ is positive and all the rest are negative.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Use auxiliary variables. Let $u_i \geq 0, v_i \geq 0$. Then we can write $x_i = u_i - v_i$ and $\vert x_i \vert = u_i + v_i$.

Comment: So:  $u_1 - v_1 + .... + u_i- v_i = 1$ and   $u_1  + v_1 + .... + u_i + v_i = 1$?

Comment: $x_i$ becomes $u_i - v_i$ and $\vert x_i \vert$ becomes $u_i + v_i$.

Comment: There is nothing to prevent both $u$ and $v$ to be strictly positive, so this way you only get an upper bound for $|x|$. For instance if $u=2,v=1$ then actual $|x|=|2-1|=1$ whereas $u+v=3$. If you really want to do exact sum of absolute values then you need binary variables and a mixed-integer problem, since the constraint is not convex. For example see https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/mio.html#exact-1-norm